# How to debug QProcess script to find the line error comes from?

Tags: python, c++, qt, qprocess

I have a small piece of code to execute a python script from Qt c++. How can I debug? Below I know the problem is "import nltk" but how can I understand that in a full project. I ran the python code in Spyder and even I put the python interpreter path same in both Qt and Spyder but in Spyder it runs correctly and tmp.json file is created while in Qt the tmp.json file is not created.

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QProcess>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QProcess p;
    QStringList params;
    params << "F:/NLP/google_corpus/scrape_python/qt/cpy2/someFunction.py";

    p.start("C:/Users/A/anaconda3/python.exe", params);

    qDebug() << "Hello World" << p.error();
    if ( p.state() == QProcess::NotRunning ) {
        return -2;
    };
    //p.waitForFinished(-1);

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

**someFunction.py**

```
import json
import sys
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\A\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions')
sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\A\\.ipython')
import nltk
#nltk.data.path.append('.')
previous_tokens = ["hey", "how", "are", "you"]
json_object = json.dumps(previous_tokens)
with open('F:\\NLP\\google_corpus\\scrape_python\\qt\\cpy2\\tmp.json', "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write(json_object)
```

Edit: sys path were different in Qt python and Spyder so I added lines below:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\A\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions')
sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\A\\.ipython')
```

But still the same poblem.

Comment: Either your python process' working directory is different in this Spyder thing, or it sets some additional environment variables that your Qt process is not setting.

Comment: @Botje If you mean python working directory yes they are the same. I added environment variables in Spyder (Tools-->Environmet variables-->path) to the qt python script but same problem.

Comment: Please edit your question with the error message you get. Also please post the contents of Python's `sys.path` in both.

Comment: @Botje I edited and add all environment variables in spyder into qt python script. Same problem!

Comment: Did you purposefully leave out that one \ on the `sys.path.append` line that probably matters? Also, Python is happy with forward-slashed paths.

Comment: Sys.path in spyder: ['C:\\Users\\A\\anaconda3\\python38.zip', 'C:\\Users\\A\\anaconda3\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\A\\anaconda3\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\A\\anaconda3', '', 'C:\\Users\\A\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Users\\A\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\Users\\A\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\A\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'C:\\Users\\A\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions', 'C:\\Users\\A\\.ipython']

Comment: And `sys.path` is now identical between the two? What error are you still getting?

Comment: Yes they are identical. When I add "import nltk" to both scripts, in Spyder it runs correctly and tmp.json file will be created while in Qt the tmp.json file wont be not created.

Comment: Maybe it is created but not where you expect it to be. Print the value of `os.getcwd()` and check _that_ directory.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the python interpreter to another one in another path and it worked although the spyder interpreter is different!The new  one:

"C:/Users/A/anaconda3/pkgs/python-3.8.3-he1778fa_2/python.exe"

I also appended nltk library path to the sys path.